# Facebook API Page Posts Gatherings Issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Would love to have some input on this, could be something simple that I am overlooking here ...

I am trying to get a list of Page Posts via ../posts and/or ../feed.

The main objective here is to get the "posts" that have call_to_action and is_hidden is true.

When I call in

```
curl -i -X GET \ https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/507498379399991/feed/?507498379399991/feed/?fields=id,from,message,link,caption,actions,privacy,status_type&access_token=
```

It will run all the posts, expect the ones that I want.

When I call in the post directly, keeping in mind I am not the admin and do not have access token for this page. We're just doing searches and getting relevant pages..

```
curl -i -X GET \ https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/507498379399991_618948374921657?fields=call_to_action,is_hidden,is_published,is_popular,status_type,type,actions,message
```

Works perfectly ...

```
{
  "call_to_action": {
    "type": "SHOP_NOW",
    "value": {
      "link": "XXX"
    }
  },
  "is_hidden": true,
  "is_published": false,
  "status_type": "shared_story",
  "type": "link",
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Like",
      "link": "XXX"
    },
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "link": "XXX"
    },
    {
      "name": "Share",
      "link": "XXX"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Love it! Only a few left!",
  "id": "507498379399991_618948374921657"
}
```

Is there not a way to call these specific type of posts directly ?

Am I just simple and can't see the solution ?? LOL!

Appreciate the input.

Comment: The API does not offer such filtering capabilities.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "filters" - those posts don't actually show up at all in the json return. They're hidden unless called directly, so I am trying to figure out how to call them.

So what do you think they're doing here " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fC9QzyuLKyw " I am see the posts in the api though.

Comment: Why would you assume that you can get a page's hidden posts without a page access token?

Comment: Because I did ... look at the question.

Comment: You did get a single post (because although it has is_hidden set, it is visible on Facebook, because it was boosted or used in an ad or something like that) - but that does not mean you are entitled to get a _list_ of hidden posts for a page that you have no admin access to.

Comment: You're right, but I see many sites and coders creating tools with the ability. LIke I showed in the youtube like, so there must be a way to do it. There is always information available from Facebook in the apis, we just have to make it look for it in a way that isn't normal. I have done it for years, but this one has eluded me.

Comment: Well if a video starts with saying they are reverse engineering things, then I am pretty sure it is not using legal APIs, but rather scraping (which is not allowed without explicit prior approval from Facebook.)

Comment: His comment about reverse engineering could go either way, he's not the sharpest tool in the draw. Not even a coder, and his english - well. LOL! Anyways, that's an example, there is a large amount of people doing it. My thoughts where the same as you pointed out as I try to stay well within the API guidelines, but when I started pulling the data with the direct post id - my thoughts went wild.